# DriverDistractionAPI does not prevent user interaction when vehicle is moving

Tags: android, fleetboard

In my app I'm using DriverDistraction API to get notified about the moving and restriction state. However independant from the state the user can perform any action.
What do I have to do in order to block user interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API does only notify the application about the state and that it shall block user interaction. You have to implement this functionalitiy according to the state.